# PowerMock and Mockito NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I want to mock static method.

```
@PrepareForTest({PersistenceCookieThreadLocal.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UserBcImplTest {}
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.getName()Ljava/lang/String;

dependencies:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12"/>
<dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-core" rev="2.8.9"/>
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-module-junit4" rev="1.7.4"/>
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-mockito2" rev="1.7.4"/>
```

I've gone through many articles but none of it has worked for me yet.

Stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.getName()Ljava/lang/String;" type="java.lang.NoSuchMethodError">java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.toInstanceName(DefaultMockCreator.java:149)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:193)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:107)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
```

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace to the question?

Comment: added @arkascha

Answer (score 1):

Make sure versions align that means you have to use powermock 2.x version for mockito 2.8.9+.
Also make sure you are not loading two different version of same jars.

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

```
Mockito       PowerMock
2.8.9+           2.x
2.8.0-2.8.9      1.7.x
2.7.5            1.7.0RC4
```

Comment: @prranay you have to use powermock 2.0+ version.